# Searching on the searchbar in google page should open the link in my website. How to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, search, schema, google-search, google-search-api

If you search for a website on Google, let's say flipkart, another search bar is seen below which has the placeholder "search flipkart.com" and if we search anything on this searchbar, the corresponding page on flipkart.com opens up.

I want to implement this on my website as well.

Can someone please help me with this ?

What I could figure out was that schema changes have to be done on the index/home page (PFA the code). I tried this wrt my website but the changes are not being reflected on google.

```
<script type="application/ld+json" nonce="9142258105932804691">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://www.flipkart.com/",
    "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://www.flipkart.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        },{
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "android-app://com.flipkart.android/flipkart/de_sq_seg_-search.flipkart.com-_{search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    }]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Whatever we search on google (the lower searchbar) is appended to **http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=** and opened in a new tab.

Comment: *but the changes are not being reflected on google* Just to make sure, you checked that googlebot scraped your page *after* you made the changes, right?

Comment: Search sitelinks don't show up on every page, and the algorithm of picking the links and search is a secret. First after you put this scheme you need to wait for google to scrap your content and second is that even if you put this code doesn't mean that you will have search box. Google will decided if you shout have it. Not sure if you have sitelinks already and add Search it will appear after google update the index for you page.

Comment: Here is article about them https://moz.com/blog/sitelinks-search-box